# what are you allowed to lie about?

Tags: halacha, emes-truth-honesty

we learn from sarah that in a situation where you can get a person very angry (which is equated to idolatry) it is OK to lie to them. in what other situations is it OK to lie to a person?

Comment: Similar question here: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4623/bending-truth-to-prevent-bad-feelings

Comment: More specific question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18107

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x11183

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71136/is-there-a-problem-with-lying

Answer (score 2):

When there is a serious risk of causing bad relations between people if the lie is not told.

See [*K'subos* 17](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=17&format=pdf). This is learned from the acceptability of praising an apparently unpraiseworthy bride on her wedding day. I have vastly oversimplified the issue, but the point the *G'mara* is making - as evidenced by *Beis Shamai*'s objection to *Beis Hillel*, which shows that *Beis Hillel* was really suggesting lying and not just evading the question - is that we have lower standards for distancing oneself from falsehood when there is a great danger involved (even non-capital danger).

Comment: @waf a bride is considered a queen on her wedding day, dont u think you are REQUIRED to lie for that reasno?

Comment: @avrohom Yes, I think that is what the רבנן hold in that גמרא. But far be it from me to pasken.

Answer (score 0):

http://naalehupdate.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/when-its-ok-to-bend-the-truth/