# Are you allowed to lie to maintain a good reputation?

Tags: sheker-false

The Torah states "Midvar Sheker Tirchak" (stay away from falsehood). However during certain situations, such as maintaining peace or avoiding ayin hara, it is permissible to lie.

Is there a leniency to allow deceit when your reputation is on the line?

Comment: What scenarios are we talking about wife? Work? Children?

Comment: Maybe you should edit that in to clarify

Comment: Let's say work or shidduchim..

Comment: I am curious to know if there's ever a leniency I don't want to limit it to one particulars case.

Comment: For marital harmony it is on certain instances permitted.  But in general it's not

Comment: Mefsresh, where can I look to learn more about this topic?

Comment: There are books that deal with this. But try typing in Google "when is it permitted to lie halacha " and see what comes up

Comment: any luck? I hope you found something

Comment: @Mefaresh, google actually brought me back here:https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=COtqVbe0BvDksATfzIGAAg&url=http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/what-are-you-allowed-to-lie-about&ved=0CCAQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHjRV-sAg5kk5VPzmEtvLxtkA-TsA&sig2=JUpMWiKxdsr9lSRot0mSFQ it seems that the question is a duplicate. :)

Comment: Let us keep to shidduchim. It really depends if the other side mind or not. For instance I was once asked if the bochur was a talmid chochom. He was more than the FIL but not the greatest. But I reckoned that he would be quite happy with him so I said yes and it went ahead and everyone is happy.

Comment: What does "FIL" mean?

Comment: I think it means father in law

Comment: @cham I'm not sure someone lying to make a shidduch between two men can be considered revelatory about the view of the Torah...;)

Comment: Hhhmm how about stealing to maintain one's honesty?

Comment: @user I can't think of an example where that would be required.

Comment: @Ani it was meant to be a snarky ironic comment. If a good name doesn't represent the honesty of the person to whom it belongs, what makes it a good name? The false perception to others and its misrepresentation?